# Запуск функции в определенное время через aiogram и aioschedule

Tags: python, aiogram, aioschedule

Всем привет! Помогите разобраться с отправкой сообщений через Aioschedule. Как не менял код, не могу добиться отправки сообщений в определенное время

```
import datetime
from config import open_weather_token, bot_token
from aiogram import Bot, types 
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
import aioschedule as schedule
import time
import asyncio

bot= Bot(token=bot_token)
dp= Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start_command(message: types.Message):
  await message.reply ("Привет, {0.first_name}! Напиши мне название своего города и я пришлю сводку погоды!".format(message.from_user))



@dp.message_handler()
async def get_weather(message: types.Message):

  code_to_smile= {
      "Clear": "Ясно \U00002600",
      "Clouds": "Облачно \U00002601",
      "Rain": "Дождь \U00002614",
      "Drizzle": "Дождь \U00002614",
      "Thunderstorm": "Гроза \U000026A1",
      "Snow": "Снег \U0001F328",
      "Mist": "Туман \U0001F32B"
  }
  try:
      r= requests.get(
          f"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={message.text}&appid={open_weather_token}&units=metric")
      data= r.json()
      city = data["name"]
      cur_weather= data["main"]["temp"]
      weather_description= data["weather"][0]["main"]
      if weather_description in code_to_smile:
          wd= code_to_smile[weather_description]
      else:
         wd= "Посмотри в окно, не пойму что там за погода!"

      humidity = data["main"]["humidity"]
      pressure = data["main"]["pressure"]
      wind = data["wind"]["speed"]
      sunrise_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunrise"])
      sunset_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunset"])
      length_of_the_day = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunset"]) - datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
          data["sys"]["sunrise"])

      await message.reply(f"***{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')}***\n"
            f"Погода в городе: {city}\nТемпература: {cur_weather}C° {wd}\n"
            f"Влажность: {humidity}%\nДавление: {pressure} мм.рт.ст\nВетер: {wind} м/с\n"
            f"Восход солнца: {sunrise_timestamp}\nЗакат солнца: {sunset_timestamp}\nПродолжительность светового дня: {length_of_the_day}\n"
            f"Хорошего дня!"
            )
  except:
     await message.reply('Проверьте название города')

@dp.message_handler()
async def job(message: types.Message):
  await message.reply("привет привет")

async def scheduler():
  schedule.every().day.at("13:23").do(job)
  while True:
     await schedule.run_pending()
     await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def on_startup():
  asyncio.create_task(scheduler())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(on_startup())

if __name__ == "__main__":
  executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае стоит делать так.

```
async def job():
  await bot.send_message(text="привет привет")
# если нужно отправлять много смс, то стоит добавить эту строку
# await asyncio.sleep(3)
```

Еще можно сделать по другому

Вот тут стоит добавить передачу параметров, потому что функция "job", просит 1 параметр (message: types.Message)

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def get_weather(message: types.Message):
  schedule.every().day.at("13:23").do(job, message=message)
...
```

И тогда можно будет запланировать эту задачу только в функции в которой есть необходимый "message".